# WPF: How to do a Word 2007 like context toolbar?

Tags: wpf-controls

I'm starting with WPF and would like to show a Word 2007 like toolbar when selecting a text in text editor. The toolbar looks like this :

[alt text http://cdn.cloudfiles.mosso.com/c54102/x2_b4b4ca](http://cdn.cloudfiles.mosso.com/c54102/x2_b4b4ca)

Would like to know how to achieve the following

- fade in fade out effect on a toolbar
- split buttons

Could you please point me to the ressources where to start or what standard WPF controls should I use (Popup control, or ToolBar, or others).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for fade you can use transparency property of control and wpf animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question. I think that the better thing is to use mini-toolbar from Office UI for developper. You can get it from here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx

And click the link "Licence the Office UI".